# Integration of an interpolated function with negative values to be taken positive

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I have an interpolated function that was based on a list of data points taken from a csv

```
s = Import["C:\\data.csv"];
power = s[[All, {1, 2}]];
interpower = Interpolation[power, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

The graph of the interpolated function looks very much like a ListLinePlot of the data points :

[image]

Now I need to integrate this interpolated function in such a way that everything below x-axis would be considered positive. Of course regular integration takes everything below x-axis as negative values. Simple inversion of negative data points increases the result of integration since resolution isn't good enough. I tried to apply Abs[] to the interpolated function which made it look like this:

[image]

It seems like just what I need but now the problem is that if I try to integrate this function:

```
result = Integrate[Abs[interpower[x]], {x, 0, 0.0004}]
```

It gives the following result:

[image]

This is of no use to me because I need just a number as my result. Is there a way I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a number, you should use `NIntegrate`, not `Integrate`. The former is for numerical integration, the latter for symbolic integration.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped. NIntegrate is the answer.